# Get memory usage of mysql query during runtime

Tags: mysql, memory

Is possible to obtain used memory in a running query?

Something like:

```
mysql> SELECT MEMORY_PEAK as memory; #return memory usage by mysql before run query
mysql> SELECT id FROM table WHERE id>2; #run query
mysql> SELECT MEMORY_PEAK as memory; #return memory usage by mysql after run query
```

and return something like (return 17kb):

```
+----------+
|  memory  |
+----------+
|  20100   |
+----------+

+------+
|  id  |
+------+
|  3   |
+------+

+----------+
|  memory  |
+----------+
|  2026767 |
+----------+
```

or

`mysql> USAGE SELECT id FROM table WHERE id>2;`

and return something like (return 17kb):

```
+---------+
|  USAGE  |
+---------+
|  16767  |
+---------+
```

Is this possible?

I need it to do various tests and see which engines queries and performs better (personal experience).

Comment: @tombom I disagree.  The question is quite straightforward: "is there a way to *directly ask* MySQL about memory usage by a specific query?"

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL 5.7, assuming you're using mostly INNODB tables, you can see how much memory is currently being used by running this query:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

You can see the maximum amount of memory your DB will ever use by running this query:

```
SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size
+ @@query_cache_size
+ @@innodb_buffer_pool_size
+ @@innodb_log_buffer_size
+ @@max_connections * ( 
    @@read_buffer_size
    + @@read_rnd_buffer_size
    + @@sort_buffer_size
    + @@join_buffer_size
    + @@binlog_cache_size
    + @@thread_stack
    + @@tmp_table_size )
) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't really adhere to this.  My server says max memory with your query of 36.4 GB.  I've watched it eat 120 GB just for the MySQL process daily.  To be clear though I'm also on MySQL 8.

Comment: @TonyMaro are you using INNODB? MyISAM tables are totally different.

Answer (score 3):

The answer appears to be "not yet."

It looks like this is being added to MySQL Server 5.7.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-summary-tables.html