Azure memory management
This is probably an Azure question but i can't get a sensible response from MS.
Did anything change on Azure's memory management for MariaDB and MySQL in the last few months?
I'd been running 5 MariaDB servers on Azure for 2 years or so with no problems. Then about 2 months ago all 5 started reaching 100% memory and crashing. MS could only tell me it was "workload" and to increase (i.e. double) the vCores/memory.
The workload hasn't changed in those 2 years but I did that and the servers ran ok. But at twice the expense.
MariaDB is being retired on Azure anyway so i brought forward my migration to FLex MySQL servers.
I'm finding that these MySQL servers are also hitting 100% memory every few hours... but at least they don't crash; they just kick users out and reduce memory usage and carry on. Nevertheless i'd like to keep this to a minimum.
I believe the usual formulae for calculating memory usage is "different" in Azure; certain parameters in Azure (e.g. max_connections and max_allowed_packet) default to extremely high values that would normally be discouraged. I've reduced them but no change in memory usage.
Slow Queries isn't telling me anything interesting.
There may be lots of smallish improvements to be made to some queries but the fact remains that this was perfectly stable for 2 years... then suddenly across 5 servers there's now a problem.
Each server has about 80 - 100 customer databases of identical structure. About 110 tables and 30 views in each database. Triggers for insert, update and delete on about half the tables. Databases range is size from 50mb to 100GB. About 150 concurrent connections on each server at any one time.
Any thoughts?

i should add the MariaDB servers all had 40GB memory.

MariaDB version 10.3. MySql version 8.0.37

you should add new information to our question and also read https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-connection-handling-and-scaling/  15000 connections  and each start a heavy query , that would bring down any server

150 concurrent connections to each SERVER... not each database.

lets say 150 mb for every connection + depending on queries and join even much more, but mysql produces an error log where it describes exactly if something is wrong

Update for anyone else struggling on Azure....
.... although we're encouraged to stick with Azure's default server settings they aren't limiting MySQL/MariaDB to any realistic memory maximum.
using this

SELECT (
(
(@@innodb_buffer_pool_size) +
@@innodb_log_buffer_size +
@@key_buffer_size +
( @@max_connections *
( @@binlog_cache_size +
@@binlog_stmt_cache_size +
@@bulk_insert_buffer_size +
@@join_buffer_size +
(@@max_allowed_packet) +
@@read_buffer_size +
@@read_rnd_buffer_size +
@@sort_buffer_size +
@@thread_stack +
@@tmp_table_size
)
) +
+
( @@open_files_limit * 1024)
) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS max_memory_GB;


the default settings give > 150GB of memory.
By reducing max_connections, Max_allowed_packet and innodb_buffer_pool_size i was able to set the max memory to  < 32GB and things are now stable.

N.B. credit due to Ryan Shillington for the calculation: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56454/get-memory-usage-of-mysql-query-during-runtime

Again for anyone finding this in a search... on Azure at least things seem most stable if that memory query above results in about 75% of the VM/Container's physical memory.
On this server with 32gb memory that means dropping max_connections to 165, max_allowed_packet to 32mb and innodb_buffer_pool_size to 15461882265
